# Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS):

Tags: php, redirect

I am not getting this error on my local host, only when i upload to my server does this error appear, on one of my pages. any idea what i need to change?

Comment: Some more information please? Anything...?

Comment: what else can i provide? i have no idea what is causing this to happen.

Comment: First of all, where exactly that error is coming from. Secondly, what have you tried? *Any* additional indicators about what could be happening. Then, what does your application consist of? Do you do anything with redirects at all or does it seem like a web server problem. Just *any* information you can provide that may seem relevant.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have run into this error in a web browser in which a webpage I went to redirects to another web page that redirects back to the original endlessly,  I have also run into situations where a programming error continuously reloads or redirects the page to itself.

The way to trouble shoot this type of problem is to actually watch the requests your browser is making to the server.  You should be able to see multiple individual requests before this error comes up.

You can see the requests your browser makes using the network tab of the developer tools in Chrome (Ctrl+Shift+J) or the network tag of Firebug in firefox.  I think IE9 has a network tool in their developer tools (F12) but I cant remember,   and I cant think of a good enough reason to open IE9 to check.  But if it doesn't have a network tool you can install the free version of HTTPWatch,  which allows you to watch the individual requests made by your browser.

And,  if none of these work,  you can always install Fiddler or WireShare which sniff the packets and requests made by your browser.

Comment: Using this advice I located my specific related issue.  Noting for future developers with my issue.  I am moving an old app I have not touched in a year and a half from Heroku to my own server (Ubuntu 18).  In order to run SSL on Heroku, I had to use sslRedirect() from the heroku-ssl-redirect npm library.  When moving to a standard server, even on non-SSL ports, the express server was still redirecting in a loop.  On the SSL port, it also got stuck in a redirect loop.  By taking out this line, the express server now serves the app with no issues redirecting.  I wish I had more detail, but hth.

Answer (score 0):

localhost and web-servers are different path for your files so you need to edit .htaccess file for get actual base-path and add this line of code int it

```
RewriteEngine On

# Some hosts may require you to use the `RewriteBase` directive.
# If you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive, it should be the
# absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
RewriteBase (your physical path)

.......
```

its all about .htaccess error