# too many redirects in express

Tags: node.js, session, express, cookies

I want to handle all my cookies and session stuff in a function then redirect to the destination path. I use this function in Express:

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next){
    if('_id' in req.session)
        next()
    else if('userInfo' in req.cookies){
        req.session._id = req.cookies.userInfo._id
        next()
    } else {
        res.redirect('../login')
    }
    res.end()
})
```

but browser print this error:
**net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**
what's the problem?

Comment: Try to remove the `res.end()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when a web browser is redirecting you to another web page which then that web page redirects you back to the same browser again. Your configurations are wrong. `app.all('*', ..)` runs again and again whenever a request is made, which causing repetition.

You need to have better configurations than `app.all(`*`..) //all`. You need to specify it more so that it doesn't repeat itself.

I would say limit it down to some `url`s and not all of them. You could do

```
app.get('/cookieCheckerPage', function(req, res){
//code here
});
```

Also please see [Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544869/error-310-neterr-too-many-redirects)