# Forecfully redirect HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, http, https

The current code in .htacess is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Its build-in codeigniter, base URL in codeigniter has been changed to https after installing SSL. now if we are accessing with https://mywebsite.com we can access https secured website but f we are accessing with http://mywebsite.com we can't access https secured website. My requirement is that I need to redirect HTTP to https. i found may article but due to my lack in the knowledge it's not working

Comment: And also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376219/htaccess-redirect-http-to-https/27029144

Comment: i didnt get a solution from it. inside tat there need server details and port number

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: i changed the entire code to the code provided by u... now its shows   This page isn’t workingcvcngr.in redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: Cleaning the cookies might help. If not post your complete .htaccess.

Comment: i tried clearing cookies no change... the complete htacess code is given in the question and I replaced the entire code by your code but it shows error mentioned above

Comment: This means the redirection is working ;).
You have a loop somewhere in your (html)code. The server error-log or browser console output should help to find the looping-links

Comment: how can i find it... is there any way

Comment: But the ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS is another question (following). Try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544869/error-310-neterr-too-many-redirects

Comment: Feel free to accept the solution ;)

Comment: if i share my url can u help me

Comment: you can PN me. I will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

put this on your config.php

```
$config['base_url']  =  "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['base_url'] .= preg_replace('@/+$@', '', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])).'/';
```